# SQLITE can't delete simple row

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-delete

I touch the button and nothing happens.

It just shows the written word and the row which I want to delete still remains in the table.

```
public void deleteword (View view) {
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB1",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    EditText deleteword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.deleteword);        
    String delete = deleteword.getText().toString();        
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Word WHERE uword='"+delete+"'");
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), delete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();   
}
```

Comment: are you sure that's exactly how the word appears in the db? whitespace'll throw it off. e.g. `where uword='[space]foo'` matchines completely differntly from `where uword='foo'`

Comment: there aren't any whitespaces, when I delete Toast, restart application and touch the button, Eclipse writes nothing in Log, on the command db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Word WHERE uword='"+delete+"'"); is no answer

Comment: Something to consider...  Is there a transaction or commit statement?  You're going to have to read up on this yourself.  But you need to check if there is a transaction/commit statement happening some where.  Perhaps there is a way to set your sqlite driver to automajically commit every statement.

Comment: Have you tried the operation from the sqlite3 command line?

Comment: Also, please used prepared statements instead of concatenating your parameters!

Comment: the doc says that the method you are using has no mean of returning you any information regarding, for example, the number of affected rows. Why do you use `execSQL`?

Comment: what's more, `execSQL(String)` is a proxy method for `execSQL(String, Object[])`, which is explicitly documented as not being for `DELETE` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String delete = deleteword.getText().toString();        
db.delete(Word, uword+"=?", new String[] (delete));
```

Ref; 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DeleteDbRow